# Correct syntax in Controller.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

In **View.php** file `<?php echo $ticket->player_id ?>` is working. But in **controller.php** it is not working. What is the correct syntax for Controller.php?

I am trying to use it here

```
'include_player_ids' => array('<?php echo $ticket->player_id ?>'),
```

The following is the sample code from controller file which are working properly

```
// Send Email
            $email_template = $this->home_model->get_email_template_hook("ticket_reply", $lang);
            if($email_template->num_rows() == 0) {
                $this->template->error(lang("error_48"));
            }
            $email_template = $email_template->row();

            if(isset($ticket->client_username)) {
                $username = $ticket->client_username;
                $email = $ticket->client_email;
                $first_name = $ticket->first_name;
                $last_name = $ticket->last_name;
            } else {
                $username = $ticket->guest_email;
                $email = $ticket->guest_email;
                $first_name = $ticket->guest_email;
                $last_name = "";
            }
```

Comment: You cannot echo something inside an array. Also, if you didn't declare `$ticket` in your controller.php, then you can't use that variable.

Comment: @Infiltrator it is already used in controller in many lines and it is working properly

`if(isset($ticket->client_username)) {
    $username = $ticket->client_username;
    $email = $ticket->client_email;
    $first_name = $ticket->first_name;
    $last_name = $ticket->last_name;
   } else {
    $username = $ticket->guest_email;
    $email = $ticket->guest_email;
    $first_name = $ticket->guest_email;
    $last_name = "";
   }`

Answer (score 3):

In **controller.php** ,

```
$data['ticket'] = 'your data will be here';
```

In **view.php**,

```
'include_player_ids' => array($ticket->player_id),
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Its already in php tags so you do not need to place `<?php ?>` again just assign variable directly

```
'include_player_ids' => array($ticket->player_id),
```

Comment: what issue are you still getting? @Selim?

Comment: When I reply the ticket OneSignal push notification is now delivered to client

Comment: In the controller the wanted data can probably be found in `$data['ticket']` so insted this should be `'include_player_ids' => array($data['ticket']->player_id),`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
'include_player_ids' => array($ticket->player_id),
```

Please post the output of $ticket

Comment: I am new in php. Can you please tell me the command to make this

Comment: if you have the $ticket variable in controller just print_r($ticket); after the variable.

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected 'print_r' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: do you have $ticket or something like $data['ticket'] in your controller. Or can you please let me know how you are passing $ticket variable to the view file ?